# Why Popen need pressing Enter to return back to shell

Tags: python, popen

I want to execute shell commands with bash in my Python script, getting real-time printing message in the screen. I use the following line to do this:

```
subprocess.Popen(my_commands, shell=True, stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=sys.stderr, executable='/bin/bash')
```

Everything looks good expect that after the shell commands are finished, the input cursor is still invisible. I have to press the Enter key to active the shell again. So what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have two shells, `shell=True` and `/bin/bash`

If you set `shell=False` you will not see the output on the console.  You will have to use `PIPE` and/or `subprocess.communicate()` to get the output (depending on what you want).